# What is partial[1:] doing in this code

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to understand the `_full_path` from [this](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) example.

```
  def _full_path(self, partial):
        if partial.startswith("/"):
            partial = partial[1:]
        path = os.path.join(self.root, partial)
        return path
```

What does the function do? Specifically, what does this line do?

```
 partial = partial[1:]
```

It seems like some kind of list manipulation -- but I can't find syntax like that in [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) document.

What is the root property of self that is getting called?

Can somebody explain a little bit about what is happening in that code.

Comment: remove start '/' of partial

Comment: Slicing is mentioned in the document you linked to; you just missed that the end can be omitted to default to the length.

Comment: simply creating a slice of the array. In other words it is slicing off everything before the item at index 1 and then it keeps the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Because os.path.join will take later path start with '/' as base, try this:

```
print os.path.join('/a', '/b/')
```

it return '/b/', so you have to check and remove begin slash when you join path.

str is a sequence type, check here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 1):

That line drops the starting "/".

The function itself gives back the "full path".